# Wordpress jQuery Error preventing plugin from running

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm getting an error in a Wordpress site that's stopping a plugin from working.

Google Dev Tools console shows the following error:

[image]

My question is ... aside from indicating an error, what exactly does this mean? Is it an error in the version of jQuery being loaded (1.12.4)? Or, if not, how do I track down what the error actually is?

Comment: I think it tries to parse the `=#` as an operator. Did you try using `[href='#']`?

Comment: @Taha Paksu, thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Yippee! I think I've solved this one.

I'm not very confident using Google Dev. Tools or messing with jQuery but blind persistance seems to have paid off in this instance.

My reasoning was as follows:

As @Taha Paksu suggested, the problem was with the reference to [href=#]. Since the guys at jQuery.com are awesome dudes who know their stuff I figured the problem wasn't with the jQuery library file itself.

So, I did a search for [href=#] in all the other JS files associated with the WP website which pinpointed a particular file (main.js) as the culprit. This file actually came with the theme I'm using ... not cool, guys!

In main.js I changed all 5 references to [href=#] to [href="#"], saved and uploaded to server.

Bingo! The plugin now works. I know, in the scheme of things, it's only a small win but, for a newbie like me, it's a triumph.